# Radio buttons not passing value in Firefox with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, codeigniter, firefox

I have this review site, with a form for users to enter their reviews, example: http://www.thecrowder.com/index.php/userreviews/sites/99_Designs (click on 'submit review')

I'm using a jQuery [star rating plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/)  and it's working fine in Chrome. However, there's some problem with Firefox and IE - it doesn't recognize the value being sent and I get an error that the 'rating' variable is missing.

If I remove the ':checked" in the jquery, I don't get an error but obviously also get '0' as the rating. Is there a different way that I should write this for the other browsers?

The review form:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Site reviewed:</td>
    <td><input readonly type="text" id="site" value="<?php echo ucwords($cleanSitename); ?>" class="required"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td> <input type="text" id="name" class="required" > </td>            
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Review:</td>
        <td><textarea id="messageUser" class="required" ></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Rate this site:</td> <!--jquery star rating system -->
        <td class="required">
            <div>                       
                <input type="radio" value="1" class="star" name="rate"/>
                <input type="radio" value="2" class="star" name="rate"/>
                <input type="radio" value="3" class="star" name="rate"/>
                <input type="radio" value="4" class="star" name="rate"/>
                <input type="radio" value="5" class="star" name="rate"/>                               
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button id="submitReview2">Submit</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#submitReview2').click(function() {
    var profile = $('#site').val();
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var message = $('#messageUser').val();
    var rating = $("input:radio[name=rate]:checked").val();
  }
```

BTW, I'm using codeigniter if it makes any difference. 
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `input[name=rate]:checked` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get the number of stars selected:

```
var rating = $(".star-rating-control .star-rating-on").length;
```